# Why destructor doesn't free array memory?

Tags: c++, valgrind, destructor, delete-operator

My question is why destructor doesn't free memory of my temp array? Valgrind tells me that I used new operator in my constructor but didn't delete memory after that. When I simply write `delete temp`, I got many errors in Valgrind like Invalid read of size, double free etc. Can you tell me guys what's going on here?

```
array_xyz(const int r, const int c, double **arg_array) {

    rows = r;
    cols = c;
    array_xyz *temp = new array_xyz();
    temp->arr = new double *[rows];
    temp->rows = r;
    temp->cols = c;
    arr = new double *[rows];

    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        arr[i] = new double [cols];
        temp->arr[i] = new double [cols];
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < rows; j++) {
        for (int k = 0; k < cols; k++)
            temp->arr[j][k] = arg_array[j][k];
    }

    arr = temp->arr;
    //delete temp; -> doesn't work, valgrind tells that I free memory twice
}

array_xyz() {
    rows = 0;
    cols = 0;
    arr = NULL;
}

~array_xyz() {
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        delete []arr[i];
    delete []arr;
}
```

Comment: Just because you asked your C++ runtime to free the memory, it doesn't mean that it will be released to the OS immediately (other allocations in the page may also need to be freed).

Comment: 1) `temp` is not freed when constructor finishes. 2) `arr = temp->arr;` overwrites pointer to memory, allocated by `arr = new double *[rows];` without freeing it first. 3) why do you even need `temp`?

Comment: `arr`  will eventually be deleted in the destructor of the object you are constructing, so deleting `temp` (with the same address in it) will invalidate the `free` in the destructor, and all access in between.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After this statement

```
arr = temp->arr;
```

the both pointers `arr` and `temp->arr` points to the same extend of memory.

If you add this satetment

```
delete temp
```

then the destructor of the class `array_xyz` frees this extent of memory (and the extents pointed to by elements of the dynamically allocated array). Also the destructor of the created object also will delete the same extent(s) of memory because its own pointer `arr` points to the same memory. So there will be attempts to free the same memory extents twice.

It is not clear why you are using an intermediate dynamically created object pointed to by the pointer `temp`. It is entirely a redundant code that only confuses readers of the constructor.

Answer (score 5):

You allocate both `arr` (and all its rows) and `temp_arr` (and all its rows).  Then you do `arr=temp_arr;`.  It does NOT copy values of `temp_arr` to `arr`. Instead, it forces `arr` to point to the same address as `temp_arr`.  The whole memory allocated to `arr` previously is now orphaned (there is no pointer to it, so you cannot free it, and it serves no usable purpose).  If you delete `temp_arr`, it would automatically delete `arr`, as they now point to the same place in memory.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you I got it. I wanted to copy values from arg_array to arr, good point that temp wasn't even needed there.

Here's solution:

```
  array_xyz(const int r, const int c, double **arg_array) {

    rows = r;
    cols = c;
    arr = new double *[rows];

    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        arr[i] = new double [cols];
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < rows; j++) {
        for (int k = 0; k < cols; k++)
            arr[j][k] = arg_array[j][k];
    }

}
```

Comment: As an aside, you can integrate the allocation in the second loop. No need to iterate twice.